# Show $x^4+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Show $x^4+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$.

I need to make use of Eisenstein's criterion, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Eisenstein doesn't seem relevant here (it's a condition for irreducibility in $\mathbb Q[x]$).  But it's only degree $4$!  if it factors then either it has a root (easy to check) or it factors into two quadratics (just try to solve for the coefficients).

Comment: $(ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+ex+f)$ so $ad=1, ae+bd=0 , be+cd+af=1, bf+ce=1, cf=1$ like this?

Comment: Well, yes.  Only you can assume the coefficients of $x^2$ are both $1$ (divide through by $a$).

Comment: $b+e=0, be+c+f=1, bf+ce=1, cf=1$

Now what?

Comment: In it's current form, it does not apply to Eisenstein's criterion. However, by making a shift x + n, it may.

Comment: So $(x+5)^4+(x+5)^2+(x+5)+1$? But what prime do I use?

Comment: Use $b+e=0$ to eliminate $e$.  Now you just have three equations in three unknowns.

Comment: I think you are over thinking this.  There are only $4$ possible values for, say, $c$. Pick one.  Say $c=1$.  That means $f=1$.  Can you get a solution this way?  If not, then try $c=2$.  Going through the four cases is extremely fast.

Comment: Can I not use Eisenstein's criterion like the other user said?

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion pertains to polynomials in $\mathbb Z[x]$.  It is a condition for irreducibility over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: $c=1$: $b+e=0$ and $b+e=1$ so no.
Is this right?

Comment: $c=2$: $b=-e$ and $be=-3/2$ , $b+4e=2$ no.
etc

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest way (I'd say).  The posted solution by @JackD'Aurizio gives another approach; one that works a lot better for larger primes.  After all, the approach I sketched relied on the fact that you could search the cases quickly.  But perhaps the general method relies on more algebra than you have currently studied?

Comment: @lulu, Quick question: Why can't I factor the quartic into (x-a)(x^3...) i.e how do I check it has no roots? Do I sub 0,1,2,3,4 in and check?

Comment: Yes.  just check all the elements.

Comment: @lulu Eisenstein's Criterion works for just integral domains as well; if $f(x) \in R[x]$ with $f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$, $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$, $a_0, ..., a_{n-1} \in P$ but $a_0 \not \in P^2$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible. Only the way I understand it (and I just learned all of this yesterday) it's not useful to apply Eisenstein when $R$ is a field, since it only has trivial ideals; it would be better to apply it to the ring $S$ whose field of fractions is $R$ and then use Gauss' Lemma; however, I don't even know if $\mathbb{F}_5$ is the field of fractions of anything

Comment: @lulu Maybe do you know?

Comment: Only of itself.  The natural map from $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb F_p$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $x^4+x^2+x+1=(x^2+ax+c)(x^2+bx+d)$ and you search for $a,b,c,d\in F_5[x]$.

Comment: That becomes even faster if we notice that we must have $a+b=0$ to ensure that the coefficient of $x^3$ is zero, and $cd=1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^4+x^2+x+1$ were reducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$, it would have an irreducible factor with degree $\leq 2$. Since the polynomial $x^{25}-x$ is the product of all the irreducible monic polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_5$ with degree $1$ or $2$, it is enough to prove that over $\mathbb{F}_5$ we have
$$\gcd(x^{25}-x,\,x^4+x^2+x+1)=1$$
to deduce that $x^4+x^2+x+1$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_5$. That is a completely algorithmic task.